# Angular2 - ng-if with 2 blocks?

Tags: angular

I have a problem with angular 2 which I cant solve yet :( I try to display data of a web.api. That works - but I want to create a bootstrap part with 4 columns like followed. And therefor I need to change the html every 4 items. I need 1 Block before every 4 items:

```
<div class="row">
```

and one after the 4 items:

```
    </div> <!-- to close the open row -->
<div class="row">
  <br />
</div>
```

But If I try to do this with ng-if - the whole block inside is blown out - and if I try to do this

```
    <template [ngIf]="(i+1)%4 == 0">
  <div class="row">
</template>
```

I get error of unclosed tag :(

Is there a solution? I would be very happy. I hope I could describe my problem sufficiently.

```html
             <div class="container" *ngFor="let item of _DataInterface; let i = index">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="row box">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 picture">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 detail">
    Test1
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="row box">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 picture center-block">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 detail">
    Test2
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="row box">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 picture center-block">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 detail">
    Test3
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="row box">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 picture">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 detail">
    Test4
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- close open row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <br />
                </div>

  <!-- next row -->
  <div class="row">
   <!-- next 4 items .... -->

           <!-- again a little distance -->
          <div class="row">
              <br />
          </div>
        </div>
 </div><!-- container close -->
```

**update**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(i+1)%4 == 0"> 
  <div class="row"> 
  <br /> 
</ng-container> 

<ng-container *ngIf="(i+1)%4 == 1"> </div> 

</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `<ng-container>` for that. `<ng-container>` is a "virtual element" that is never added to the DOM:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="expr">
  <!-- content here -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Wow, what a fast answer! Thanks! It seems to be the same error " div requires end tag"

        <ng-container *ngIf="(i+1)%4 == 0">
            <div class="row">
                <br />
        </ng-container>

And the block on the end:
        <ng-container *ngIf="(i+1)%4 == 1">
            </div>
        </ng-container>
VS show error "End tag is missing matching start tag"

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly. You can't have the start of the tag inside one `<ng-container>` and the end tag within the other one. The `<ng-container>` has to contain full valid HTML.

Comment: Oh ok, but this is actually what I need :( It will be closed but after 4 items within the ngfor loop.

Comment: There is no way to do that. You might to duplicate more of the HTML to get around that requirement.